# Recent Ubuntu 20.04.1 kernels crash

Tags: nvidia, kernel

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS with nvidia-460 drivers in ppa.

Until 5.4.0-62-generic kernel, I have no problem with my computer.
Since 5.4.0-64-generic, I cannot get boot screen.
Since 5.4.0-65-generic, even recovery mode makes screen freeze.

My computer is consist of

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6600 CPU @ 3.30GHz
- 16GB RAM
- nVidia RTX 3070 (with 700W power)
- Some USB devices (keyboard, mouse, webcam)

for more information the output of `lspci` is as follows:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation B150 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA104 [GeForce RTX 3070] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

I tried to delete `quiet splash` in grub to get the log of boot.
But I couldn't find something meaningful.

Comment: Did you add "nomodeset" in grub? Secureboot enabled?

Comment: no secureboot. "nomobdeset" keyword was in the recovery mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. Simple solution

I solved this problem later by installing
`linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.4.0-66-generic`
where Linux kernel 5.4.0-66-generic and `nvidia-driver-460` were installed.

I found that there was no nvidia kernel driver under `/lib/modules/5.4.0-66-generic`, where the kernel modules are. So, I searched for the package of nvidia kernel module.

#### 2. Why 5.4.0-62-generic works?

There were nvidia kernel driver modules under `/lib/modules/5.4.0-62-generic/updates/dkms`. I searched for the origin by `dpkg -S`, but it had no information.

After some investigation, I found that `linux-headers-${linux-version-and-build}` triggers to compile dkms and install updates/dkms. And I found that `linux-headers-5.4.0-66-generic` package was not installed automatically, while `linux-headers-5.4.0-62-generic` was installed due to the package dependency.

#### What makes the problem more difficult

It seems that current FBDEV cannot drive RTX 3070.
I tried to change screen using Cttl + Alt + Function key but the screen was freezed.